# razor pay with ionic-capacior having having problem : 'Razorpay/Razorpay-Swift.h' file not found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

main.h file

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import <Razorpay/Razorpay-Swift.h>

@interface Main : CDVPlugin

@property NSString *callbackId;

- (void)open:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

They have mentioned in their documentation

We don't support capacitor because of the app support dependency, for more details go through this link.

https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova